# facing issue while calling nested function in swift ios

Tags: swift

```
func check(a: () -> ()){

        func a(){

            print("A Calling")

        }

        a()

    }
```

Calling function

```
check {
    print("Check Calling")
 }
```

In the above code, i am not able to call a() function and it will directly be executing "check calling "

**Result** : "Check Calling"

When i am calling check function it should be execute a() function also  and order should be

Result should be:

"A Calling"

"Check Calling"

Comment: What's your expect output? Because currently, it's unclear if you want to call your nested function or the "completion block"/closure... Start by naming them differently as suggested and you might see it...

Comment: updated more info

Comment: updated params name

Comment: Okay, now your code prints `A Calling`, not `Check Calling` as you described. Your code _does_ execute `a()`, which appears to be the thing you want. Question solved?

Comment: it's not calling print("Check Calling")

Comment: @user1374 What is it you want to happen? Do you want to call the nested function or the closure that you are passing in.

Comment: i want when i call to check () it will first execute a() and then i will execute check within call back @Abizern

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code in your question is that you do not call the nested function at all. It doesn't help that you've named it the same as the passed in function which is perhaps why you are having trouble isolating the issue.

This works

```swift
func check(completion: () -> Void) {
    func localFunction() {
        print("A Calling")
    }

    localFunction()
    completion()
}

check {
    print("Check Calling")
}
// Outputs:
//
// A Calling
// Check Calling
```